# Errors when using MCMT to create a multi control cz gate and trying to measure

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, quantum-computing, circuit, qubit

Multi control cz gate:

[image: multi control cz gate]

The error is saying that:

> [Experiment 0] Circuit mcmt contains invalid instructions {"gates": {ccz}} for "statevector" method. ,  ERROR: Circuit mcmt contains invalid instructions {"gates": {ccz}} for "statevector" method.'

Comment: Interesting but unclear where the error occurs. Using qiskit? Have you found the answer at https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.transpile.html?

Comment: yes kind of I was doing a project so there I got this problem then I used transpiler and then it worked

Answer (score 1):

I get the answer later ... if we use Multi control cz gate then we need to call the transpiler and then transpile it like this

```
from qiskit import transpile
t_qc = transpile(qc, sim) # sim = simulation
```